# php send mail to client and business

Tags: php, html, ajax, email

I am struggling with the following.When a user fills in a form looking like this, the inquiry gets sent to us to follow up the lead, but I need to find a way to modify my email script to send a confirmation email to the user aswell

[image]

My email script looks like this:

**MY QUESTION HOW DO I MODIFY THIS TO SEND A THANK YOU CONFIRMATION TO THE USER**

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$eventType = $_POST['eventType'];
$nrGuests = $_POST['nrGuests'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$suburb = $_POST['suburb'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$refferal_page = $_POST['page'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!isset($refferal_page)){
$refferal_page="Source Unknown";    
}

    $to_email       = "unknown@yahoo.co.nz"; //Recipient email

    //TODO Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().

    $suburb     =   filter_var($_POST["suburb"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject        = "You Have a New Booking!";
    //Add booking INFO here;
    $message        = "A new Enquiry has been received from http://www.xxxxx.com.au. Please find details below and follow up:";

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email."\r\nPhone Number : ". $mobile."\r\nEvent Type: ".$eventType."\r\nNumber Guests:".$nrGuests."\r\nState: ".$state."\r\nSuburb:".$suburb."\r\nIP ADDRESS:".$ip."\r\nMessage:".$msg."\r\nReferal Page Source:".$refferal_page;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
    if($send_mail)
    {   
    echo '<h1 class="page-header">Enquiry Successfully submitted</h1>';
}
else if(!$send_mail){

    echo'<h1 class="page-header" style="color:RED">OOPS...SOMETHING WENT WRONG, PLEASE TRY AGAIN!</h1>';

}
        }//server request method
        else{

        echo'<h1 style="color:red">SUBMIT A FORM PLEASE!</h1>';
        }
        ?>
```

**EMAIL THAT COMES TO US**

A new Inqury has been received from www.xxxx.com.au. Please find details below and follow up:

**FROM:** Ryan XXX

**Email** : aass@testms.com

**Phone Number** : 334533

**Event Type:** Aniversary

**Nr Guests:** 34

**State:** Melbourne

**Suburb:** XYZ

**IP ADDR:** 162.111.255.111

**MSG:** this is a test. please disregard
Referal Page Source:aniversary

Obviously I dont want user to see this I just want to add something like *"Thank you we will get back to you soon"*

***Any idea how I can modify the above script for us to get inquiry form but also for user to get an confirmation email?***

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Have you even bothered to read the PHP manual?

Comment: @crypticツ no I havent not really a developer just a business man

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $eventType = $_POST['eventType'];
    $nrGuests = $_POST['nrGuests'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $suburb = $_POST['suburb'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $refferal_page = $_POST['page'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(!isset($refferal_page)){
    $refferal_page="Source Unknown";    
    }

        $to_email       = "unknown@yahoo.co.nz"; //Recipient email

        //TODO Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().

        $suburb     =   filter_var($_POST["suburb"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $subject        = "You Have a New Booking!";
        //Add booking INFO here;
        $message        = "A new Enquiry has been received from http://www.xxxxx.com.au. Please find details below and follow up:";

        //email body
        $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email."\r\nPhone Number : ". $mobile."\r\nEvent Type: ".$eventType."\r\nNumber Guests:".$nrGuests."\r\nState: ".$state."\r\nSuburb:".$suburb."\r\nIP ADDRESS:".$ip."\r\nMessage:".$msg."\r\nReferal Page Source:".$refferal_page;

        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
        if($send_mail)
        {   
        echo '<h1 class="page-header">Enquiry Successfully submitted</h1>';

$EmailTo        =   $email;
$subject        = "recipient subject";
$message_body = "Hi ".$name."recipient message";

$headers        = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers        .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers        .= "From: yourname<$youremail>\n";
$send_cust_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);



    }
    else if(!$send_mail){

        echo'<h1 class="page-header" style="color:RED">OOPS...SOMETHING WENT WRONG, PLEASE TRY AGAIN!</h1>';

    }
            }//server request method
            else{

            echo'<h1 style="color:red">SUBMIT A FORM PLEASE!</h1>';
            }
            ?>
```